# How can I make class variables behave the same on windows and linux with python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, linux, windows, operating-system, python-multiprocessing

When I run the following script, I observe different behavior depending on the operating system:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class C(object):
    VAR = 'DEFAULT'


def print_c():
    print(f'C.VAR = {C.VAR}')

def main():
    print_c()
    C.VAR = 'CHANGED'
    print_c()

    p = Process(target=print_c, daemon=True)
    p.start()
    p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

## Linux

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux puddle 4.14.134 #1-NixOS SMP Sun Jul 21 07:04:43 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ python --version
Python 3.6.9

$ python class-variable-in-subprocess.py
C.VAR = DEFAULT
C.VAR = CHANGED
C.VAR = CHANGED
```

## Windows

```
H:\workspace>python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

H:\workspace>python class-variable-in-subprocess.py
C.VAR = DEFAULT
C.VAR = CHANGED
C.VAR = DEFAULT
```

From the example above, you can see that under Windows the static class variable `C.VAR` is re-initialized with `DEFAULT` during process creation.

I suspect that this is because of the inherent difference between the `fork` and `CreateProcess` system calls. Nevertheless, I am looking for a simple way to make class variable initialization behave the same no matter where the code runs.

Comment: I also created [a public gist for this](https://gist.github.com/Enteee/dafad1acc020581090ddcedb517e7f77)

Comment: Even though I am asking for consistency, I am generally more interested in making the code on Windows behave like on Linux. But I think for the completeness of the question, an ideal answer should possibly provide a way to achieve the opposite as well.

Comment: That's due to the different [start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) on Windows vs. Posix. Basically, on Windows (start method `spawn`), a *new* class `C` object is created in the child process, with its class attribute `VAR` being `DEFAULT` as per the definition whereas on Posix (with start method `fork`) the *existing* class `C` object from the main process, in its altered state, is available and accessed in the child process.

Comment: So, in short, this issue is unsolvable :) Or probably, change it to passing parameter in may work? `print_c(C)`

Comment: @Sraw I don't think passing the class object works either. Arguments passed to the child process are pickled; unpickling in the case of a class means creating a new class object from its definition and that will have `VAR = 'DEFAULT'`. The only way to achieve consistency I currently see is to make Linux behave like Windows, i.e. explicitly setting the start method to `spawn`, so that Linux doesn't use `fork`.

Comment: I got to that question because I was following [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) from the official FAQ. But this would me I have to pay special attention to my globals when using sub processes while still trying to be compatible with windows and linux. Argh, that's annoying.

Comment: I was actually investigating on how i maybe [could implement fork](https://github.com/mirror/newlib-cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/fork.cc) with python in userspace.. But nah that's too complicated.